# How to upload photo from UWP to web service?

Tags: c#, web-services, azure, uwp, azure-web-app-service

I am currently working on an UWP project where I need to take a photo using the device's camera before uploading it to my online service which is hosted on Azure.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: This is dependant 100% on the target Webservice. The Display Technologies only impact is how the user raises the event or wich timer to use to run it regularly.

Comment: Did you already know how to take a photo in UWP? Did you already have a web service on azure? Did your web service have API for uploading images? What you have done?

Comment: Yes I have already achieved it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

To upload photos to Azure, it's best to use Azure Blob Storage.   Here's a link to the [Quickstart guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet?tabs=macos) as well as some sample code.